# Can't connect in SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql, ssms

Well, I'm getting this error... Can't connect to any DB instance so... Which is quite annoying. It all worked before I had my laptop sent to manufacturer for reparations (new motherboard, but programs were still on the laptop when I got it back). Any help?

"
Er is een netwerkfout of een exemplaarspecifieke fout opgetreden tijdens het maken van verbinding met SQL Server. De server is niet gevonden of is niet toegankelijk. Controleer of de exemplaarnaam correct is en of in de instellingen van SQL Server externe verbindingen zijn toegestaan. (provider: SQL-netwerkinterfaces, error: 26 - Fout bij zoeken van opgegeven server/exemplaar)"

Attempt to translation:
"A network error or example specific error has occurred while connecting to SQL Server. The server has not been found or is not accessible. Check whether the example name is correct and whether external connections are allowed in the settings of SQL Server. (provider: SQL-networkinterfaces, error: 26 - Error while searching the given server/example)"

Comment: Is the SQL server local or remote?  Can you ping it?

Comment: It is a local server

Comment: Hi parthannun, you should try pinging your server using the command-line. If you do not get a response, this suggests that you are not connected to the same local network your SQL Server is on.